# why jQuery .find() only return first element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `find()` function to get all my children element, with `each()` function I am expecting it return all element, but it only get first element. Is there any misunderstanding with these two functions?

```js
if ($('.test').length > 0) {
  var srcset;
  $(".test").each(function(index, ele) {
    srcset = $(ele).find("source").attr("srcset");
    console.log(srcset);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<picture class="test">
  <source srcset="###">
  <source srcset="###">
  <source srcset="###">
  <img src="#" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: It's not `.find`. It's `.attr()`

Comment: you are not iterating through result of find . iterate through result of find will give you desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the first one because [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) will return the first element attribute, you have to loop through the selection using [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), and one more thing you can use `".test source"` selector directly, here is a working snippet:

```js
if ($('.test').length > 0) {
  srcset = $(".test source");
  srcset.each(function(i, el){
    console.log($(el).attr('srcset'));  
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<picture class="test">
  <source srcset="###">
  <source srcset="###">
  <source srcset="###">
  <img src="#" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know .attr() only return first element, I thought it will return value every time in each loop.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `.find("source")` returns all the elements as you can see here:

```js
$(".test").each(function() {
  var source = $(this).find("source");
  console.log(source.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<picture class="test">
  <source srcset="###">
  <source srcset="###">
  <source srcset="###">
  <img src="#" alt="">
</picture>
```

You can see `source.length` returns `3` above, but the issue is with `.attr("srcset")`. When we use `.attr()` it only returns the value of the first matched element in the collection. To fix this issue you simply need to loop through all `source` elements and then get `srcset` like:

```js
var srcset;
$(".test source").each(function() {
  srcset = $(this).attr("srcset");
  console.log(srcset);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<picture class="test">
  <source srcset="/abc">
  <source srcset="/123">
  <source srcset="/example/object/">
  <img src="#" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: yes, thanks, that's make sense why I am not geting the rest of elements